# paypal payment direct pro sandbox only works for US accounts?

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal

I have created multiple sandbox accounts in paypal developer. I have enabled business pro on all these accounts in order to receive direct payments. However, with the business pro accounts that are created with a country not in the USA, the curl command to send a direct payment returns a 10501, invalid merchant configuration, where as the US account on succeeds. The curl command is from the classic API which I believe should also be available for Australia. Is there something im missing?

Answer (score 1):

`PayPal Payments Pro` or `Website Payments Pro` is available only in US,UK and Canada. Yes, it supports AU merchants for Website Paymemt PRO Hosted Solution. AU merchants, PayPal does not officially promote Dodirectpayment. Instead you can use Payflow to do `DodirectPayemnt`

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/au/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_wp-pro-overview-outside states that website payments pro is available in australia.